# Align images in rows

Tags: html, css

```css
 
.box1, .box2 {
    display: flex;
  }
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.box2 .left, .box1 .right, .box2 .right, .box1 .left {
  width: 100%
}

.box2 .left {
  padding: 25px 10px 25px 75px
}
.box1 .right {
  padding: 25px 75px 25px 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="left"><img src="https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="right">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt, beatae iure perspiciatis.
      Reprehenderit sapiente numquam totam possimus necessitatibus. Enim nostrum rem quasi voluptates. Consectetur, est aliquid. Iste voluptas laborum provident harum! Ipsam pariatur velit iste quam, dolorum inventore rem molestias modi nemo?
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="box2">
    <div class="left">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt, beatae iure perspiciatis.
      Reprehenderit sapiente numquam totam possimus necessitatibus. Enim nostrum rem quasi voluptates. Consectetur, est aliquid. Iste voluptas laborum provident harum! Ipsam pariatur velit iste quam, dolorum inventore rem molestias modi nemo?
    </div>
     <div class="right"><img src="https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve to change this and to get both images connected with their corners, like this: [image]

How to achieve the result from image? Also, i want to keep the paddings of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Was it necessary? The indents are preserved. In css, I marked the edits. Also, to improve the visualization of your images, you can add rules - `height: 100%` and `object-fit: cover` for `img` tag (It's not obligatory).

```css
.box1, .box2 {
    display: flex;
  }
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.box2 .left, .box1 .right, .box2 .right, .box1 .left {
  width: 100%;
  flex-basis: 50%; /*add this it*/
}

.box2 .left {
  padding: 25px 10px 25px 75px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /*add this it*/
}
.box1 .right {
  padding: 25px 75px 25px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /*add this it*/
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="left"><img src="https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="right">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt, beatae iure perspiciatis.
      Reprehenderit sapiente numquam totam possimus necessitatibus. Enim nostrum rem quasi voluptates. Consectetur, est aliquid. Iste voluptas laborum provident harum! Ipsam pariatur velit iste quam, dolorum inventore rem molestias modi nemo?
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="box2">
    <div class="left">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt, beatae iure perspiciatis.
      Reprehenderit sapiente numquam totam possimus necessitatibus. Enim nostrum rem quasi voluptates. Consectetur, est aliquid. Iste voluptas laborum provident harum! Ipsam pariatur velit iste quam, dolorum inventore rem molestias modi nemo?
    </div>
     <div class="right"><img src="https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your image to a background image. In this case, you need not specify the height and width of an image, which means truly responsible.

Just change the container height and width for a different viewport and it will always take 50% height and width..

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

.image{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg')
}

.box-1, .box-2{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.image, .content{
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.content{
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1"><div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt,</div></div>
  <div class="box-2"><div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt, beatae iure perspiciatis.</div>
  <div class="image"></div></div>
</div>
```